# Converting single ended to differential signal with differential amps

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to transform my 0-5V analog signal to differential signals. I have on hand a bunch of [TI INA106KP](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina106.pdf). I'd like to use one to invert my signal and the other one to non-inverting. The doc show how to get a inverting and a buffer. The buffer however has a gain of 11. Can I still use the two together?

also, is a simple voltage divider good enough to power this? I want to run my signal down 20ft of shielded twisted pair wires.

[image: Schematics]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ground the 100K resistor (Pin1) in the first example, rather than connecting it to the input, to get a gain of +10.0 for the non-inverting side.

I don't know what you mean by power it through a voltage divider. It should have a power supply of something like +10V and -10V regulated to work properly. +/-15V is what it is specified with.

20 feet of shielded twisted pair wires will be okay, provided the capacitance of the wire does not exceed 50pF/foot, otherwise the amplifier may go unstable. You should also consider protecting the outputs of the amplifier with some hefty TVS bipolar diodes. It would be better if you could put at least 100 ohms in series with each output.

Comment: The opamp has a minimum +/- 5v requirement, can I go with that? I wanted to use a voltage divider to create a virtual ground and +5,-5 like :http://tangentsoft.net/elec/bitmaps/vgrounds/buffer.png

Comment: If you look at page 4, you can see that +/-2V is plausible with +/-5V supplies, so if you divide the 0-5V input by 25:1 you can get +/-2V outputs (+/-4V differential voltage). The power supply question will require a schematic showing where the input signal common will be connected.

Comment: Trying the above circuits with just a constant voltage input of 12v, the inverter gets me -11v and the buffer gets me 8v. Is this ok?

Comment: Nope. Show your schematic, please.

Comment: just did, sorry for the crudeness

Comment: I don't see the input in those squiggles (you'll probably need to buffer the virtual ground, if it will even work), and hope you realize you'll have to attenuate the 0-5V input to compensate for the gains of +/-10 or the outputs will hit the rails.